# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < inside JS file when importing into HTML

Tags: javascript, html

This error is driving me mad

I have a `index.html` file that lives in my public directory

I have a newRelic script that was living in my html in script tags and was working all fine

I have now moved it out to a separate js file and am importing it

`<script src="/path/to/newrelic.js"> </script>`

I know it's the right location coz if I put a different path I get a 400

when it fines the file I get this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` and when I click on the newRelic script in the browser it says it has a `<!doctype html>` at the top. it doesn't!!!

for some reason it seems that it's pointing at the index.html file that im trying to import it into. coz when I removed the `doctype` from the html file it then pointed and errored at the next html tag. there is no html inside the newrelic file. it's just a minified script

how can I get it to point at the correct file instead of itself?

also don't mark this as a duplicate please. I have resisted posting as I have already read all the articles on stackoverflow about this but all the solutions didn't work for me.

Comment: I think you have to use js file name newrelic.js as <script src="/path/to/newrelic.js"> </script>

Comment: @VindhyachalKumar sorry I should confirm I am doing exactly that

Comment: "I know it's the right location coz if I put a different path I get a 400" - this should be 404 I guess?

Comment: This sounds like a problem with the web server.  What is the URL to the script file?

Comment: What happens when you try to open the script in your browser? It if worked right, it would show script source, but in your case, it should show some HTML page, which might give a clue on what is misconfigured

Comment: the url is: `public/templates/newRelic.js` and the index.html I'm trying to import it to lives at `public/index.html`

Comment: @cyberskunk opening it in the browser just shows me the script with no console errors. script starting with `window.`

Comment: What happens when you provide the full URL as a source for the script?

Comment: Is it `src="public/templates/..."`, or `src="/public/templates/..."`…?!

Comment: the first one @deceze. but it doesn't really matter

Comment: I get the same error with either

Comment: It surely *does* matter. `/public/...` will always find the file in the same location, while `public/...` **is relative to the URL you're currently on.**

Comment: this is why im confused. I just did this: `/public/templates/newRelicasfasffasafa` and it's still complaining about the `<` token. that file doesn't even exist?!

Comment: Exactly! That file doesn't exist! You're getting an **HTML** 404 error page, and that is not valid Javascript, and Javascript complains about `<` of the starting HTML tag.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is valid javascript though :/. surely valid javascript is anything between script tags?

Comment: but even when I put `function(){}` inside that javascript file (which is deffo valid js) I get an error...

Comment: Open your browser's developer tools' network inspector. Check what the network request and response is for that Javascript file.

Comment: it's a 200 response but the file is the html file...

Comment: ok think I get what's going on sort of, how can I tell webpack to use this as .js file instead then?

Comment: "The" HTML file? What HTML file? Does it say anything about an error or something in "the" HTML file? In a nutshell: your server is returning an HTML file when a Javascript file is requested. **We don't know why that is without knowing more about your server.**

Comment: it's returning the main `public/index.html` instead of the requested javascript. what do you need to know? im using webpack and the dev server. no express or koa

Answer (score 3):

If the file's not accessible (for instance, not found or permission denied), you might get a response that's an HTML page default for the error.

It looks like this is exactly what's happening.

If you try to open that file directly in the browser (using e.g. `https://www.example.com/path/to/newrelic.js`, it will most likely not show the JS file but an HTML page with an error.

Comment: no I opened it in the browser and it should be in the script and no errors. starting with `window.` etc

Comment: If you get a `400` error how can you see it in the browser? Did you open it by typing the url or by using the "open file..." menu from the browser?

Comment: open file menu from the browser

Comment: As I said, try opening it using the full URL, like `https://www.example.com/path/to/newrelic.js`. If you don't use the same URL that you try to use from the HTML you'll not see the error.

Comment: I don't get what you mean. the script is on my computer. Ive copied it to a file and so im importing it that way.. it doesn't live under https

Comment: If you're getting an HTML document as a response, it means you're opening your page through some URL in the browser and that there's a server running that serves the page. The JS file HAS to be accessible through the server or it will fail. If you want to try it out ONLY locally, you can use the *full* path with `file://`, and I mean *full*, something like `<script src="file:///home/Users/someone/mysite/public/templates/newRelic.js"> </script>`